Is there a reason why the Maclaurin coefficients of the Riemann zeta function are asymptotically close to -1?
If I look at the numerical values of the Maclaurin series of the Riemann zeta function I see that they approach -1 extremely quickly. In fact, if I take $\zeta(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n$ then numerically I find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty(a_n+1)^2\approx 0.25658169$ which converges very quickly.
This seems to be stronger than just asking why $-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{x}{x-1}$ approximates $\zeta(x)$ so well.

Let $f(z)$ be any function with a simple pole at $z=z_0$ with residue $r_0$ and otherwise entire. Then $g(z) = f(z) - r_0/(z-z_0)$ is entire, and so in its Maclaurin expansion $g(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n z^n$, the coefficients $g_n$ decay superexponentially (by the root test or by Cauchy's integral formula), $b_n \ll_A A^{-n}$ for every $A>1$. But then the Maclaurin expansion $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n$ is dominated by the behaviour of $r_0/(z-z_0)$:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n z^n = \frac{r_0}{z-z_0} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n z^n = \frac{-r_0/z_0}{1-z/z_0} + \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n z^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{-r_0}{z_0} \biggl( \frac z{z_0} \biggr)^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_n z^n,
$$
and hence
$\displaystyle
f_n = \frac{-r_0}{z_0^{n+1}} + O_A( A^{-n} ).
$
